# Programmatically delete a photograph from Mac Photos

Tags: swift, macos

How do I programmatically delete a photograph from the Mac Photo's app, and have the changes also apply to iCloud? I'm working on an app which should move photographs to the bin based on a number of criteria.

I use the MLMediaLibrary API to find the images in the first place, which works:

```
class PhotoFinder : NSObject {

    var _onLoaded: ([PhotoReference]) -> Void
    var _mediaLibrary : MLMediaLibrary
    var _observerAdded : Bool
    var _loading : Bool
    var _mediaSource: MLMediaSource!
    var _album: MLMediaGroup!

    init(onLoaded: ([PhotoReference]) -> Void) {

        let options: [String : AnyObject] = [
            MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey: MLMediaSourceType.Image.rawValue,
            MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey: [MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier]
        ];

        _onLoaded = onLoaded;
        _mediaLibrary = MLMediaLibrary(options: options);
        _observerAdded = false
        _loading = false

        super.init();
    }

    func load() {
        if (_loading) {
            return
        }

        if (!_observerAdded) {
            _mediaLibrary.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "mediaSources", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil);
            _observerAdded = true;
        }

        _loading = true
        _mediaLibrary.mediaSources
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        guard let path = keyPath else { return }

        switch path {
        case "mediaSources":
            loadSources()
        case "rootMediaGroup":
            loadAlbums()
        case "mediaObjects":
            loadMediaObjects()
        default:
            print("Nothing to do for \(path)")
        }
    }


    func loadSources() {
        if let mediaSources = _mediaLibrary.mediaSources {
            _mediaSource = mediaSources["com.apple.Photos"]
            _mediaSource.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rootMediaGroup", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
            _mediaSource?.rootMediaGroup
        }
    }

    func loadAlbums() {
        let albums: MLMediaGroup = _mediaSource.mediaGroupForIdentifier("TopLevelAlbums")!
        for album in albums.childGroups! {
            let identifier = album.attributes["identifier"]
            if (identifier?.isEqualToString("allPhotosAlbum") == true) {
                _album = album

                _album.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "mediaObjects", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
                _album.mediaObjects

                break
            }
        }
    }

    func loadMediaObjects() {
        var photos = [PhotoReference]()

        for photo in _album.mediaObjects! {
            photos.append(PhotoReference(identifier: photo.identifier, originalPath: photo.originalURL!.path!))
        }

        _onLoaded(photos)
        _loading = false
    }
}
```

I cannot find the relevant information in the official documentation.

Comment: This isn't possible?